# How to determine if an IAP is resulting in a restore (non-restore flow)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Imagine an app with non-consumable IAPs. Generally a user would buy the product and, if they uninstalled and reinstalled or decided to play on a second device, they would restore. This case is simple to handle.

However, there is another case where the user performs the normal purchase flow of the non-consumable on the second device. In this case they go through the steps of making a purchase, but instead of paying money they are told they have already purchased the item and asked if they would like to re-download it. Note that I'm not talking about downloadable content, though, just regular non-consumables.

The question is how can I differentiate this type of restore from a new purchase? Let me go through some obvious answers that don't quite work:

1. **Detect transaction state `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`** -- This type of restore is not marked with this state, it is marked `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`
2. **Compare the `originalTransactionId` to the `transactionId`** -- In this type of restore, these two values are equal.
3. **Compare the `originalPurchaseDate` to the `purchaseDate`** -- This is the closest thing to something that works. The surprise here is that for a truly new purchase these dates aren't necessarily identical. They are generally within a few seconds of one another.

Granted this is not a common flow, that most restores, when they happen, should and will happen via the normal restore flow. Nonetheless, I don't see any clearcut solution to determining whether we have a re-purchase or not.

[This page from the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html) is relevant, for reference.

Comment: As you point out, normally you don't care - the difference isn't relevant. What is the use case where you care about the distinction in your situation? Perhaps that will lend itself to identifying an out-of-band indicator... or when you parse the receipt data on app startup, build a list of items to compare against when the transaction comes through?

Comment: The use case is for internal revenue tracking since a re-download is not a revenue generating event. It's possible to sort it out on the backend with some DB magic, but it would be preferable to know up front. That's an interesting idea to look at the receipt after startup. A little tricky to test realistically as dev install builds don't start out with a receipt, but we could call refresh on startup.

Comment: Don't most of the approaches to receipt verification assume you're refreshing when it doesn't exist anyway (even in dev, where you'll get a valid receipt as long as you log in with a test user)? 

Yes, it does introduce a few bumps, but it seems to be easy enough to mod the "is re-processing?" test to (validReceipt && skuAlreadyExists).

Comment: Wouldn't internal revenue tracking have to take place on the backend anyways? Is it that much more effort on the backend to check for known transaction ids?

Comment: @ChrisPrince I believe these restores will have new transaction IDs. At the very least their original transaction ID and transaction ID are the same. You'd have to be sure you had the same user and then uniq on non-consumables purchases by product ID. This is a pretty margin case - it's probably only worth figuring it out if it can be done easily.